# Symbol to show that implication is one-sided

Tags: notation

Sometimes A => B is true, but B => A is not true and this fact is important and not obvious. Is there a short symbol to write it in order not to write "A => B and not B => A"

Comment: I don't know of one. I'd probably write "The converse is false." after the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for till now there no way to write A⇒B and B⇏A